# Spring jdbcTemplate Issues

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring `JdbcTemplate` to get all records of a Table.
But the `List` which returns from the `query()` method is not having any values even the database table has data.

My DAO Class :

```
public class AgateJDBCTemplate  {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;


    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource); 

    }

    public List<AgateObject> getAgateCounts(){
        String sql = "select counts, flag, feed_id from cd_product_reg_stage";
        return jdbcTemplateObject.query(sql, new InnerMapper());
    }
    private static final class InnerMapper implements RowMapper<AgateObject>{
        public AgateObject mapRow(ResultSet rs,int rownum) throws SQLException{
            AgateObject obj = new AgateObject();
            obj.setCounts(rs.getLong("counts"));
            obj.setProcessed_flag(rs.getString("flag"));
            obj.setFeed_id(rs.getLong("feed_id")); 
            return obj;
        }
    }

}
```

My database Table :

```
select counts, flag, feed_id from cd_product_reg_stage;



COUNTS FLAG          FEED_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
     15230 E                2556
  29611273 Y                2556
         3                  2556
     16071 E                2557
  27629913 Y                2557
     14560 E                2558
  27072698 Y                2558
     14377 E                2559
  33306196 Y                2559
```

My Main Method :

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("iCloudTest_Config.xml");

AgateJDBCTemplate agateJdbc = (AgateJDBCTemplate) context.getBean("agateJDBCTemplateMain");

System.out.println( agateJdbc.getAgateCounts().size()); // This is printing ZERO
```

Where is it going Wrong ? Is it even calling the result set and picking up the data ?  Ideally the list should contain the Objects but its still 
Empty.

Please help.

## UPDATE:

I have observed that it is not at all going inside the `mapRow` method.

Comment: might sound silly but... Do you have anything in your table?

Comment: Yes I have.  I haven given the data also in my description. Please check.

Comment: The fact that you see data doesn't mean it is in the database, if you haven't committed it isn't visible to other threads. Also are you using the same database? If the `mapRow` isn't called there is no result from the database. Generally this is due to no data being there or you aren't using the database you are expecting to use.

Comment: please do a simple `select count(1) from cd_product_reg_stage` in your application, to verify if there is really data available.

Comment: There are too many possibility that you can retrieve data from your SQL client, but not in application. (e.g. wrong schema, VPD, txn etc)

Comment: public int getCount()
 {
  String sql = "select count(1) from cd_product_reg_stage";
  int rowcount = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
  return rowcount;
    
 }

Comment: I have used a simple count query as shown in my above comment . But still i am getting the value 0.   I ran the same query in my db , and it returned 9 (There are 9 rows in my db table)

Comment: Trouble shooting tips: Check for jdbc url, if it points to correct database. Use `@Autowired private DataSource dataSource;`
    `@Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;` Use `@Bean public class AgateJDBCTemplate  {`